# Open problems in Lie symmetry theory

Tags: symmetry, big-list, conjectures, open-problem

What are some famous open problems and conjectures in Lie symmetry theory? Is there some kind of list of these problems available or possibly a historical survey of the development of theory of symmetry groups?

Comment: Does this help? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453276/what-are-the-important-open-problems-about-lie-groups 
or
https://kar.kent.ac.uk/20151/1/Clarkson-CBMS02.pdf